# How best to aggregate site statistics (especially search demand)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, analytics

I am working on a rails application that uses sunspot solr for search.  I have been asked to log (or capture in some way) each search that happens on the site; the query, the user that did the search, the result count that resulted from their search...etc, so that the company can report on what people are searching on (demand), and other things.

Before I go and make a table, that will receive an ever-growing number of rows of search data, I'm wondering if anyone has done this in a better way?  Can I use analytics (google?) in some way for this?  Is there some kind of service I can send this information too, such that we could easily pull reports, or create reports from?

In short, is there some better/smarter way than creating my own table and storing this all in our own DB?

Answer (score 0):

I had never done this, but here are some thoughts.

If you just need to store that data I think you should do it yourself.
If you need to also provide a way to analyse the data yes, see if there is anything already done (I'm not sure but it seems google analytics only support internal search using their search bar).

If your client already have some BI tool they just need a way to access the data, and it would be easier to have it in a owned DB wich you can easily be query instead of using a provider api.